# How I can attach musicID to tiktok video via TikTok API?

Tags: node.js, express, tiktok, tiktok-api

How can I attach audio, for example by audio ID, to a tiktok video before publishing via the tiktok API? I have read the tiktok API, but there are no examples about this, since the sound overlay on the original audio clip of the video is not suitable. Do you have any ideas?

Perhaps there is an option how to do this not through the API, but using node js + express

Comment: Did you already find a way to include the musicID in an API Call? Thanks!